# How can I compile a primefaces source?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In the download section of primefaces there are 3 links:

```
binary
bundle
sources
```

I use primefaces 3.4.2 and would like to recompile one java class to fulfill my needs.
I downloaded the sources. Now I would like to recompile this class, but I don't know how to achieve that. How can I compile a primefaces source?

Comment: Check out the [*Building From Source*](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Building-From-Source) article in the Primefaces wiki. The project is now hosted on github.com: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout sources from [repo](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces). It is [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) project, so build it with maven.

Answer (score 5):

From primefaces site:

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/BuildingFromSource

> PrimeFaces uses maven as the build tool. There's a custom maven plugin to generate jsf artifacts. To begin you might need to check out and build PrimeFaces maven-jsf-plugin in case the version used is not available in Prime Repository.
>
> ```
> svn checkout http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/maven/trunk/maven-jsf-plugin/ build
> ```
>
> cd to the build and do a maven install
>
> ```
> cd build
> mvn install
> ```
>
> Next thing to do is to build PrimeFaces itself, checkout the code with;
>
> ```
> svn checkout http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk
> ```
>
> cd to the primefaces folder and run maven build.
>
> ```
> cd primefaces
> mvn install
> ```
>
> Component Development
>
> PrimeFaces JSF plugin generates the necessary artifacts including component sources, faces-config.xml, and facelets taglib. Component developers only need to implement the Renderer classes of the components. Component metadata files are defined under src/main/resources-maven-jsf folder.