# Primefaces org.primefaces.component.gmap.GMap class is missing

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions, primefaces-gmap

Hi everyone I'm trying to customize #primefaces component GMap, But in github GMap class is missing.
org.primefaces.component.gmap.GMap

[Github link](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/gmap)

I'm working on PF v6.2 Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Follow de complete procedure of downloading the source and building it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compile a primefaces source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942538/how-can-i-compile-a-primefaces-source)

Answer (score 0):

Yes your problem is that Gmap is a template and is generated when you do "mvn clean package".

See GitHub Link: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/gmap

It converts GMapTemplate.java to GMap.java in /target/generated/sources/

Comment: Agreed I get why they generate the templates but it makes for working with the code locally a little bit of a pain when switching branches etc.

Comment: Yes... using annotations on baseclasses and use those to generate the xnl instead of vice-versa is much better